# how to style a preselected button in html so thst the selcted option is not displayed in dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, html-select

Hi I am working on a website and I want it bilingual i.e. spanish is its default language and I want to show a dropdown button to translate it in english.so this is what I tried.

```html
 <select name="lan" id="lan">
  <option>ENG</option>
  <option selected="selected">ESP</option>
</select>
```

So what I want is the pre-selected option should not be shown in dropdown i.e. default selected option is spanish and in dropdown the only option is english when I select english the option in the dropdown is spanish. someone please help me how can I do this.

Comment: no I didn't  can you please help me how js will work for this case??

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with adding css selector like so to your css file:

```css
  #lan option:checked {
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
<select name="lan" id="lan">
  <option>ENG</option>
  <option selected="selected">ESP</option>
</select>
```